# Command to send multiple output over email

Tags: email

I have files in below name format

1-filename.txt
2-filename.txt
3-filename.txt

1-demofile.txt
2-demofile.txt
3-demofile.txt

Now when I run shell script with below command

#!/bin/bash

Awk -F '#_' '{print FILENAME, NF}'  ?-filename.txt | uniq -c

Awk -F '#_' '{print FILENAMEME, NF}'  ?-demofile.txt | uniq -c

Then i get output as below

10 1-filename.txt 5

10 2-filename.txt 8

10 3-filename.txt 7

10 1-demofile.txt 20

10 2-demofile.txt 20

10 3-demofile.txt 20

Output which I am getting is correct
I want all these output to be sent on mail.

How to do that in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

mail -S subject  address < file is the simplest way to send file in unix. You can use file as attachment also as shown below

echo "$BODY"  | mail -s "$SUBJECT" -a file $EMAIL_ADDRESS

where $BODY has contents of email
$SUBJECT has subject
file is the file to be attached
$EMAIL_ADDRESS is email address

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `metasend` in the `metamail` package.

You need a locally running mail server (which can be something like `masqmail` that just forwards it to the "real" server).

Comment: `metamail` appears to be abandonware and most distros have dropped it. I was looking for it for a legacy project and located [archlived archlinux package](https://archive.org/download/archlinux_pkg_metamail), [Debian packages](https://sources.debian.org/src/metamail) and more [here](https://pkgs.org/download/metamail). Long gone from most major repos such as Ubuntu, etc.